# how is memory management across language implemented?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Suppose you are running a program (in a process) that mixed multiple languages, for example, we usually mix `python` and `c`, and obviously they have different memory management strategy. So, when python is trying to allocate some memory in the heap, how does it know that part of memory hasn't been used by the `C`?  And my guess is that they all call the same low level system call to allocate memory, which is done by the kernel, and that system call will handle this.

Comment: My guess would be that Python just uses `malloc` under the hood, same as C.

Comment: You are right - it all must eventually devolve down to the OS memory management system calls, one way or another.  Note that code from different languages within a process may well use different heaps with different sub-allocators, so allocating memory in one language and freeing in another may cause.....'issues' :)